# Obtain the desired value from the output of a method Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, telegram, telethon

i use a method in telethon python3 library: 
"client(GetMessagesRequest(peers,[pinnedMsgId]))"

this return :

```
ChannelMessages(pts=41065, count=0, messages=[Message(out=False, mentioned=False,
   media_unread=False, silent=False, post=False, id=20465, from_id=111104071, 
   to_id=PeerChannel(channel_id=1111111111), fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, 
   reply_to_msg_id=None, date=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1517325331), 
   message=' test message test', media=None, reply_markup=None, 
   entities=[], views=None, edit_date=None, post_author=None, grouped_id=None)], 
   chats=[Channel(creator=..............
```

i only need text of message ------> test message test

how can get that alone?

the telethon team say:
"This is not related to the library. You just need more Python knowledge so ask somewhere else"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have saved the return value in some variable, say, `result = client(...)`, you can access members of any instance through the [dot operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

```
result = client(...)
message = result.messages[0]
```

The `[0]` is a way to access the first element of a list (see the [documentation for __getitem__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)). Since you want the text...:

```
text = message.message
```

Should do the trick.